# C++ - Initialze static variable with global scope

Tags: c++

I have included a static c++ string array in the header file. I get a segfault 
when I try to access it in the source file.

Here are the details.
OS : Linux
Compiler : g++

job.hpp

```
static string values[2] = {"hello","welcome"};

class Job
{
public:
    void getValues();
};
```

job.cpp

```
#include "job.hpp"

void Job::getValues()
{
    // Seg Fault Here
    // i value is either 0 or 1 and is based on some external flag
    cout << values[i] << endl;
}
```

I believe the values array is not getting initialized. This code works with xlc++ compiler on AIX. Is there any g++ compiler flag to initialize the static variables.

Comment: Declare your static variable in the header file and define in .cpp

Comment: Thank you. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: How do you compile and link? The code itself works for me.

Comment: @OP The problem is in the code you didn't show. (Other than having a global variable called 'i').

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your 'values' array into a static attribute of the class? Something like the following might work.

**job.h**

```
#ifndef JOB_H
#define JOB_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Job
{
    public:
        Job();
        void getValues() const;

        //declare static variable in .hpp file
        static string values[2];
    private:
};
#endif
```

**job.cpp**

```
#include "job.h"

//initialize variable in .cpp file
string Job::values[2]={"hello", "welcome"};

Job::Job(){}

void Job::getValues() const
{
    cout << values[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get the same error even after implementing the steps you have suggested

Comment: Weird. I just made a small `main` driver class that instantiates a `Job` object and it compiled. I compiled it with `g++ -std=c++11 jobmain.cpp job.cpp -o jobs` and seems to be working.

Comment: I just added `Job::values[i]` to the `Job::getvalues()` method on the `job.cpp` file. Maybe that will do?